# "were" instead of "was"

Tags: verbs, subjunctives

> “We’re just happy our little girl is alive,” said Jessica’s father, Michael Paulsen, as though the state of being alive were itself a sufficient cause for happiness and not a prison of its own, at least in a phenomenological sense

I read this paragraph on the Onion News.  I wonder, why ***were*** is used as the linking verb  instead of ***was*** in the part of the sentence "... as though the state of being alive **were** itself a sufficient cause for..." ?

Comment: It's an *irrealis*, because the author is pretending to adopt a philosophical perspective which denies the notion that being alive is a sufficient cause for happiness -- this is The Onion, after all.

Comment: @StoneyB ahhh _irrealis_. That's the answer of my unasked questions, I realized that after checking wikipedia on irrealis. Thank you!

Comment: @Yirmidokuz: Don't feel bad about not understanding the usage. [The Subjunctive Is Dead! Long Live the Subjunctive!](http://www.stc-techedit.org/tiki-index.php?page=The+Technical+Stylist_The+Subjunctive+Is+Dead.+Long+Live+the+Subjunctive.) I don't know if the parenthetical remark in that link is true, but it says *English speakers **(particularly speakers of British English)** tend to avoid the subjunctive and use the conditional instead.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's why I call it *irrealis*. But the subjunctive isn't dead, it's just lying in ambush.

Comment: @StoneyB: I used to assume English was somehow "advancing" by dispensing with so many verb forms and other inflections. But (unless I've misunderstood him) John Lawler says all languages tend to cycle between high/low levels of inflection, so language evolution is really just the same as the biological kind. No particular manifestation is meaningfully more advanced than another - all organisms and languages are what they are by happenstance of prior history, and are all (on average) adequate for their required functionality.

Comment: (but I still feel it will be a *good thing* if we ditch a few more semantically irrelevant things like *"If I were you"* where *"If I was you"* means exactly the same! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The whole subjunctive thing is one of the reasons I'm of the school that ascribes tense, aspect, voice, mood, transitivity &c to the clause, not the word and sees these qualities as eliciting this or that specific form. The forms change over time, but time references and modality and so forth are still there in the clause, just expressed differently. There are no irrealis verbs, just irrealis clauses.

Comment: @StoneyB: Good point - I'm now well-schooled in the idea that a word is, say, an ***adverb** if and when it's **used** in an adverbial context, not otherwise*. But in OP's example, would not the entire clause after *Michael Paulsen* still be "irrealis" if we changed *as though* to, say, *perhaps because he thought*? And would not even the most die-hard subjunctivist balk at peddling his wares in *that* context, even though semantically/functionally it would be much the same as the original?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah--but now you're changing the meaning radically, shifting from what the author thinks (or affects to think), which is that being alive is NOT a sufficient cause for happiness, to what Michael Paulsen thinks. Even if you phrased it "perhaps because he imbecilically thought" you would still have to cast in realis (indicative) mode.

Comment: @StoneyB: You're right. In my yearning for the simplicity of a grammar that minimises complex variants with little or no semantic content, I sometimes lose sight of the fact that *irrealis* clauses/utteramces obviously *do* exist. In fact, they're a vital part of language, and no doubt sometimes it's semantically *necessary* to be able to unambiguously identify them as such. For analysis here, or just to understand speech - it comes down to the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The father is said to speak “as though the state of being alive **were** itself a sufficient cause for happiness” because the author of the article is affecting to regard the proposition that “the state of being alive **is** itself a sufficient cause for happiness” as obviously untrue. This is a standard *irrealis* use of the past form, which you have probably encountered in conditional constructions:

> If happiness **were** itself a sufficient cause for happiness, then Jessica’s father would be justified in his statement.

The author wishes us to understand that (in his opinion) the state of being alive **is not** itself a sufficient cause for happiness. On the contrary, the state of being alive is (again, in the author’s  opinion) “a prison of its own, at least in a phenomenological sense”.

I hope I need not say (but plagued as we are by the ineluctable anti-intellectualism and philosophical naïveté of the popular press and of so-called ‘democratic’ education, I feel I must) that this is intended (albeit meretriciously and by way of an inauthentic and false-conscious ressentiment) satirically.